# View part of array in angular

Tags: angular

For testing, I am using a jsonstring. Later I will get this via api. The aim is to view the data in a table. The first loop with building the header works fine, but when I try to loop thrue the products, then I got an error.

I am using angular 5

This is my jsonstring:

```
[{
  "obm": 1234,
  "tsnr": 12,
      "tsname": "Muster",
  "tsort": "ort",
  "lastupdate": "2018-03-12 02:00:00",
  "produkte": 
    [{
      "bezeichnung": "E10",
      "artikel": 2,
      "tankgroesse": 19005,
      "aktuell": 8450,
      "eintag": 9450,
      "dreitage": 11450,
      "siebentage": 14450
    }]
}]
```

And here is the html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="card-columns">
        <div class="card" *ngFor="let number of data; let i = index">
            <div class="card-header">
                {{ data[i].obm }} -
                {{ data[i].tsnr }} -
                {{ data[i].tsname }} -
                {{ data[i].tsort }}
                <small>Stand: {{ data[i].lastupdate }} Uhr</small>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="app-table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <th colspan="2">Produkt</th>
                        <th>Tankgröße
                        <th>Aktuell</th>
                        <th>-1</th>
                        <th>-3</th>
                        <th>-7</th>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr *ngFor="let produkt of data[i].produkte; let j = index">
                                <td>{{ produkt[j].bezeichnung }}</td>
                                <td>{{ produkt[j].artikel }}</td>
                                <td>{{ produkt[j].tankgroesse }}</td>
                                <td>{{ produkt[j].aktuell }}</td>
                                <td>{{ produkt[j].eintag }}</td>
                                <td>{{ produkt[j].dreitage }}</td>
                                <td>{{ produkt[j].siebentage }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Where is my mistake?

I got the error that produkt[i].bezeichnung is not defined. But when view the object in console.log, then everything is delivered.

Did I try it wrong with the loop?

[image]

Comment: Please post your error trace and not a picture of it.

Comment: please check the answer and follow the steps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your HTML file, remove these indexes like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="card-columns">
        <div class="card" *ngFor="let number of data">
            <div class="card-header">
                {{ number.obm }} -
                {{ number.tsnr }} -
                {{ number.tsname }} -
                {{ number.tsort }}
                <small>Stand: {{ number.lastupdate }} Uhr</small>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="app-table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <th colspan="2">Produkt</th>
                        <th>Tankgröße
                        <th>Aktuell</th>
                        <th>-1</th>
                        <th>-3</th>
                        <th>-7</th>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr *ngFor="let produkt of number.produkte;">
                                <td>{{ produkt.bezeichnung }}</td>
                                <td>{{ produkt.artikel }}</td>
                                <td>{{ produkt.tankgroesse }}</td>
                                <td>{{ produkt.aktuell }}</td>
                                <td>{{ produkt.eintag }}</td>
                                <td>{{ produkt.dreitage }}</td>
                                <td>{{ produkt.siebentage }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Produkt is not an array anymore, it is an object.

Remove the index j and access it directly.

```
<td>{{ produkt.bezeichnung }}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like issue with this line , where produkte is not present on your object

```
<tr *ngFor="let produkt of data[i].produkte; let j = index">
```

you can do like this

```
<tr *ngFor="let produkt of number.produkte; let j = index">
```

and for you if you are storing value in `number` in first loop `<div class="card" *ngFor="let number of data; let i = index">` than you dont need to do `data[i]` you just need to use `number`.

---

one more thing i suggest you make use of `json` and check value passed to find out what are you passing is correct or not ,for that do this on your page

```
{{data|json}}
```

this will tell you what object you are passing and `produkte` is present on object or not.

---

please check product array is present or not by using `*ngIf`

```
 <div class="card-body" *ngIf="number.produkte">
```

before running loop on product array.

---

Also do check for null or undefined for each property by making use of `?` as below

```
 <div class="card" *ngFor="let number of data; let i = index">
            <div class="card-header">
                {{ number?.obm }} -
                {{ number?.tsnr }} -
                {{ number?.tsname }} -
                {{ number?.tsort }}
                <s
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine, just a one line change -

```
<tr *ngFor="let produkt of data[i].produkte[j]; let j = index">
```

Since, the array is multi-dimensional you're missing the loop index for the second iteration. Cheers!

But its my recommendation you use this HTML -

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let number of data; let i = index">
        <div class="card-header">
            {{ data[i].obm }} -
            {{ data[i].tsnr }} -
            {{ data[i].tsname }} -
            {{ data[i].tsort }}
            <small>Stand: {{ data[i].lastupdate }} Uhr</small>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="app-table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <th colspan="2">Produkt</th>
                    <th>Tankgröße
                    <th>Aktuell</th>
                    <th>-1</th>
                    <th>-3</th>
                    <th>-7</th>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr *ngFor="let produkt of number.produkte; let j = index">
                            <td>{{ produkt.bezeichnung }}</td>
                            <td>{{ produkt.artikel }}</td> 
                            <td>{{ produkt.tankgroesse }}</td>
                            <td>{{ produkt.aktuell }}</td>
                            <td>{{ produkt.eintag }}</td>
                            <td>{{ produkt.dreitage }}</td>
                            <td>{{ produkt.siebentage }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```